# Python Numpy nonzero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I've got this numpy array of shape (31641600,2), which has some, if not many zero values in it.

Let's call the array X.

Doing:

```
print len(X)
>>> 31641600
```

But then doing:

```
X = X[np.nonzero(X)]
print len(X)
>>> 31919809
```

Don't understand why the second one is bigger. On the [Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero) it says that applying the above method should return only the non-zero values, hence the length of X should be smaller.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be due to the fact that `len(X)` only returns `X`'s length along the first axis. When you do

```
X = X[np.nonzero(X)]
```

you get a 1D array, so if you had less than 50% of zeros in `X`, `len(X)` will increase.

Consider:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: X = np.zeros((42, 2))

In [3]: X[:, 0] = 1

In [4]: X[0, 1] = 1

In [5]: len(X)
Out[5]: 42

In [6]: len(X[np.nonzero(X)])
Out[6]: 43
```

That's because `X[np.nonzero(X)]` is an array of 43 one's:

```
In [7]: X[np.nonzero(X)].shape
Out[7]: (43,)
```

**Update in response to comment:** if in fact you want all pairs where the first element is non-zero, you can do:

```
X = X[ X[:, 0] != 0 ]
```

Comment: Haha nice one! Didn't know about this! What I was trying to do basically is get rid of all nonzero entries in my array. What my (x,y) values represent are magnitudes and angles from some motion vectors, just need to discard all 0  magnitudes, along with them the associated angles.

Comment: @ClaudiuS Then you can use fancy indexing instead of `nonzero`. I updated the answer.

Comment: I can only then accept your answer and have my thanks :) I was looking into boolean indexing but was doing it wrong. Thanks again